# SHAREPOINT 2007 - Record Read Only

Tags: sharepoint, record, readonly

In a "Issue" list, I have a mandatory field called "Status", to control the status (Identified, implemented, postponed, etc.). I need to control the behavior of each record based on that field content. For certain status the record should became read only, and only admin users should be able to edit / change it.

Is there a way to implement this functionality?

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it

Create an event handler and in that event hander you can edit the permission of current list item.

If you want more help, you can comment me :)